# Use react native Text component in filter loop

Tags: react-native, coffeescript

I'm trying to render a hierarchical component view (in Coffeescript) from an object that contain parent/child relations

My object looks like

```
this.state =
  data: [
    {
      id: 1
      name: 'Category 1'
      type: 'category'
    },{
      id: 2
      parent: 1
      name: 'Task 1'
      type: 'task'
    },{
      id: 3
      parent: 1
      name: 'Task 2'
      type: 'task'
    },{
      id: 4
      name: 'Category 2'
      type: 'category'
    },{
      id: 5
      parent: 4
      name: 'Task 3'
      type: 'task'
    },{
      id: 6
      parent: 4
      name: 'Task 4'
      type: 'task'
    }
  ]
```

My current approach is as follows

```
render: ->
  <Text>Hierarchy</Text>
  { this.state.data.map( ( data ) =>
    if data.type == 'category'
      this.renderView( data )
  ) }
```

and

```
renderView: (data) ->
  <View>
    <View>
      <Text>{data.name}</Text>
    </View>
    <View>
      { result = this.state.data.filter( ( obj ) ->
        if obj.parent == data.id
          <Text>{obj.name}</Text>
      ) }
    </View>
  </View>
```

The code above however results in the following error

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found:
>   object with keys {id,parent,name,type})

I know that in the `filter()` loop the correct data is available. Somehow i can't use the React Native `<Text>` element there, but why?

Comment: filter returns the object in case it meets a condition. and you are displaying the object (result) in the view not the <Text />. you should be using <Text>result.name</Text> after computing the result before the view.

Comment: @GaudamThiyagarajan Could you please elaborate that?

Comment: this.state.data.filter( ( obj ) -> { return obj.parent == data.id  }} will return the obj that satisfies the condition. your <Text>{obj.name}</Text> returns nothing true. so result has obj itself and that's what you are trying to display. AhsanAli's answer show how to do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `return` the `renderView` method from `render`

```
render: ->
  <Text>Hierarchy</Text>
{
  this.state.data.map((data) =>
    if data.type == 'category'
      return this.renderView(data)
  ) }
```

also, you have to `filter` the`result` first and `map` over it

```
renderView: (data) ->
  { var result = this.state.data.filter(obj => obj.parent == data.id) }
  <View>
  <View>
    <Text>{data.name}</Text>
  </View>
  <View>
    {result.map(val => val.name)}
  </View>
  </View>
```

**PS:** I don't know the syntax of `coffescript` much, sorry for any typo, but the logic would work fine.

Comment: That was it, thnx

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with your code

- Inside the render function, you don't have a valid JSX syntax. Therefore you need to wrap your code in some wrapper.

  ```
  <View>
        <Text>Hierarchy</Text>
        {this.state.data.map(data => data.type === 'category' && this.renderView(data))} // Also check if your map returns the data(Since I don't know coffeescript)
  </View>
  ```
- [`Filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function creates a new array which you're trying to render in your `View`, therefore *it throws an error not a valid React Child*.

Therefore you can do

```
return (
            <View>
                <View>
                    <Text>{data.name}</Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    {this.state.data.map( obj => obj.parent === data.id &&  <Text>{obj.name}</Text>)}
                </View>
        </View>)
```